# Plugin does not obey wordpress date translation

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime

I have a wordpress plugin that I have translated everything, however only one part is not allowed to be translated, it is the date section, so I have analyzed the code, the format and the language of the date obeys the wordpress translation but only does it partially

I have this source code:

```
  $time_format = get_option('time_format');
  $date = $start->format($time_format);
```

I use the format "`j \d\e F \d\e Y"` however it does not appear translated into the Spanish language I want.

Still appears :

```
29 de September de 2022
```

When it should show like this:

```
28 de septiembre de 2022
```

I tried to use `date_i18n()` but without success it only shows me many numbers without any meaning

Example:

```
            $date = $start->format(date_i18n('j \d\e F \d\e Y'));
```

this is the output:

```
   29America/Adak 00America/Adakp3000America/Adak09bThu, 29 Sep 2022 08:00:00 -0900America/Adak 29America/Adak 2022
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Wrapping `date_i18n` into `$start->format` makes no sense whatsoever - it returns an already formatted _date_, not a _format string_. Why are you not using `wp_date`? https://wordpress.org/support/article/formatting-date-and-time/#localization

Comment: thanks for your reply, i did it like this `code`$date = wp_date( $date_format);`code`  and yes it works but unfortunately not correctly.
  This part of the code shows a sequence of dates $start->format(.. , but without it it doesn't work well but with wp_date it gives me an error.

I try to use it like this but I get an error, any ideas?: `code`$date = $start->wp_date( $date_format);`code`

Comment: What error? What does `$date_format` actually contain now? And you need to pass in the timestamp as second parameter, otherwise this will output the _current_ date & time.